# translate.googleapis.com returns "Uncaught DOMException: An invalid or illegal string was specified"

Tags: google-translate

I have a problem with adding Google Translate plugin to my webpage. It works well in Chrome but it does not in Firefox. I added this code into my HTML:

```
<div id="google_translate_element" style="display: none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

end this code into JS file:

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
      pageLanguage: 'pl',
      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL,
      autoDisplay: false, 
    },
    'google_translate_element');
}
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: An invalid or illegal string was specified
ss https://translate.googleapis.com/_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.pl.a56NrSgV284.O/d=1/exm=el_conf/ed=1/rs=AN8SPfrkdghExwoIxxyRz3pC0eYbjBK20w/m=el_main:468
    Iu https://translate.googleapis.com/_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.pl.a56NrSgV284.O/d=1/exm=el_conf/ed=1/rs=AN8SPfrkdghExwoIxxyRz3pC0eYbjBK20w/m=el_main:551
    av https://translate.googleapis.com/_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.pl.a56NrSgV284.O/d=1/exm=el_conf/ed=1/rs=AN8SPfrkdghExwoIxxyRz3pC0eYbjBK20w/m=el_main:604
    mv https://translate.googleapis.com/_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.pl.a56NrSgV284.O/d=1/exm=el_conf/ed=1/rs=AN8SPfrkdghExwoIxxyRz3pC0eYbjBK20w/m=el_main:627
    googleTranslateElementInit https://www.swinoujscie.pl/:2107
    e https://translate.googleapis.com/_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.pl.a56NrSgV284.O/d=1/exm=el_conf/ed=1/rs=AN8SPfrkdghExwoIxxyRz3pC0eYbjBK20w/m=el_main:52
    Oi https://translate.googleapis.com/_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.pl.a56NrSgV284.O/d=1/exm=el_conf/ed=1/rs=AN8SPfrkdghExwoIxxyRz3pC0eYbjBK20w/m=el_main:52
    <anonimowa> https://translate.googleapis.com/_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.pl.a56NrSgV284.O/d=1/exm=el_conf/ed=1/rs=AN8SPfrkdghExwoIxxyRz3pC0eYbjBK20w/m=el_main:628
    <anonimowa> https://translate.googleapis.com/_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.pl.a56NrSgV284.O/d=1/exm=el_conf/ed=1/rs=AN8SPfrkdghExwoIxxyRz3pC0eYbjBK20w/m=el_main:633
```

Also translate.googleapis doesn't work for my Firefox on page https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_translate

I updated Firefox but this didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue with Firefox version 102.5.0esr. In my case updating to 108.0 fixed the issue, but I am required to make it work with 102, so I am also still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue. It seems like the problem is caused by lack of proper support for the second parameter `measureOptions` of `performance.measure()` function in Firefox below v103 which some part of Google Translate widget relies on.

See MDN specification: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure#browser_compatibility

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33673850)